# Connection to db isn't closed after query ends

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, database, prepared-statement

I did this query that doesn't close the connection and I can't figure out why.
here is the screenshot that show's the number of the connections (That's why I know the connection is not closed)
[image]

Please help me figure out the problem.

this is the code:

```
@Override
    public Map<MenuItem, Long> getGtinFromIngredientByLinkedProduct(Map<Long, MenuItem> ingredientIdProductMap) {
        Map<MenuItem, Long> result = new HashMap<MenuItem, Long>();
        String sql = "SELECT INGREDIENTS_GLOBAL_TRACK_IDF, INGREDIENT_ID FROM [PWRNXGDTA].INGREDIENTS WHERE INGREDIENT_ID in (";
        StringBuilder ingredientsIDs = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        Set<Long> ingredients = ingredientIdProductMap.keySet();
        System.out.println("Ingredient id's SIZE: " + ingredients.size());
        for(Long ingredientId : ingredients) {
            if(!first){
                ingredientsIDs.append(",");
            } else {
                first = false;
            }
            ingredientsIDs.append(ingredientId);
        }
        sql+= ingredientsIDs+")";
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        QueryRunner q = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            q = super.getQueryRunner();
            con = q.getDataSource().getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                result.put(ingredientIdProductMap.get(rs.getLong("INGREDIENT_ID")),
                        rs.getLong("INGREDIENTS_GLOBAL_TRACK_IDF"));
            }
        } catch (DAOException | SQLException e) {
            logger.info(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            try {
                if(ps != null){
                    ps.close();
                }
                if(con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }
                if(q != null) {
                    q.getDataSource().getConnection().close();
                }
                if(rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Does your log reveal that any exceptions happened when trying to close a connection?  By the way, I'm pretty sure you should be closing the result set before the connection.

Comment: I took a shot at an answer below.  Even if wrong, it's one thing you can rule out.

Comment: Did you check the implementations of `Connection` that you get? If a connection pool is involved you might not be able to close the connection directly (just a guess though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your finally block, are you not creating a new connection ?

```
if(q != null) {
    q.getDataSource().getConnection().close();
}
```

The `QueryRunner` has some methods to `prepareConnection` and different `close` you could use to simplify your handling.